# How do I account for bitcoin profit on UK tax return

Tags: taxes, united-kingdom

I want to cash out some bitcoin with a profit (<£2000) from trading.

Do I need to declare it in my next tax statement?  Is it ok to just show amount bought and amount held or do I need to declare all the transactions on the various exchanges?  (I used Cryptsy for a while which is now bust so no idea how I can get the transactions from that.)